# How to adjust max_gram for text field in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

The issue is, I have an email field in elastic search documents with max_gram = 20, So if I have email_address with characters more than max_gram, it will be not found with the search query, I know I can add .sort on the field to search with the whole text but if I entered email with more than max_gram and not the whole email it will never found. So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you shouldn't create the gram on mail-id and elasticsearch already provides a [UAX_URL email tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html) to properly tokenizer the mail-id.

Still if you don't want to change it to above recommended way, then you should change the `index.max_gram_diff` setting and increase your max_gram value to higher number.

**Note, max_gram_diff is the difference between min gram and max gram.**